# Maximum weight path in a directed graph in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, graph, graph-algorithm, stored-functions

Consider a (directed) graph like this:

[image: the directed graph]

Each node of this graph represents *a step of a preparation procedure of a recipe*. To start the `step 2` the `step 1` *must* be already done; to start the `step 7`, `step 5`, `step 3` and `step 6` *must* be already done (and also every previous step); `step 1`, `step 6` and `step 8` can start *immediately* (and *simultaneously*). `step 9` is the *end-step*: there's only **one** end-step in every recipe.
Each step has a *duration time*.

I have implemented this graph in my MySQL DB in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE Step (
    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    RecipeID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Duration TIME, -- if NULL = immediate (duration: 00:00:00)
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (RecipeID) REFERENCES Recipe(ID)
);
CREATE TABLE StepSequence (
    Step INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PreviousStep INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Step, PreviousStep),
    FOREIGN KEY (Step) REFERENCES Step(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PreviousStep) REFERENCES Step(ID)
);
```

I need a *stored function/procedure in MySQL* that computes the **total time needed** for the preparation of the recipe. This time (considering that steps that can be made simultaneously are **always** made concurrently) is **the path with the maximum time**.

Considering that I **can't** create a recursive procedure, how can I obtain that result in an *iterative way*?
*(The problem that prevents me to use recursive procedures is explained in comments - any workaround that makes the code works also with a recursive procedure is accepted)*

Comment: Why can't you implement a recursive procedure?  That is the natural way to answer the question.

Comment: In fact I can but, searching on Google, I discovered that MySQL allow a max of 255 recursive calls. *Possibly* I would prefer to make a routine that works also on recipes with more than 255 steps.